# Debian 9 - IPV6 not assigning

Tags: debian, linux-networking

Simple task: I've assigned a V6 address to a debian9 box, but its not applying to the interface on reboot. The V4 address is applying. If i assign it manually using `ip -6 addr add <ipv6address>/<prefixlength> dev <interface>` then it works fine. Here's a copy of my **/etc/network/interfaces** config

> '# The loopback network interface 
>   auto lo
>   iface lo inet loopback 
>   iface lo inet6 loopback
>
> '# The primary network interface 
>    allow-hotplug eth0 
>   iface eth0 inet static 
>           address 10.190.xxx.xxx/26 
>           gateway 10.190.xxx.xxx 
>           up route add -net 10.100.xx.xxx/32 gw 10.190.xxx.xxx dev eth0 
>           # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed 
>           dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2
>
> iface eth0 inet6 static 
>           address 2607:f0x0:xxxx:ac::20 
>           netmask 64 
>  
>           gateway 2607:f0x0:xxxx:ac::2

Comment: Try doing an `ifup --force eth0` from an shell with root privs.  Tell us the error.

Comment: I get the following error: `RTNETLINK answers: File exists
ifup: failed to bring up eth0`

Comment: Might need to do an `ifdown --force eth0`.  Might also need to try commenting out your ipv4 section temporarily, and trying to down+up the interface.  The settings are applied in order and any failure will immediately abort.

Comment: This is odd. The ifup/ifdown operation works, because the interface goes down and up (as in the box becomes unreachable/reachable), but each operation throws an error. the ifup operation is the above error, ifdown returns: `RTNETLINK answers: No such process  RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address`

Comment: What tells if config, @joe this is normal i aint seen that without doing that for years

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ifupdown2` package, try to install `ifupdown` instead. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You just need **one stanza** for an interface with **ifupdown2**:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0
    address 10.190.xxx.xxx/26
    gateway 10.190.xxx.xxx
    address 2607:f0x0:xxxx:ac::20/64
    gateway 2607:f0x0:xxxx:ac::2 
    dns-nameservers 9.9.9.9 149.112.112.112
    post-up ip route add 10.100.xx.xxx/32 via 10.190.xxx.xxx dev eth0
```

The config file "/etc/network/interfaces" is not quite the same for ifupdown and ifupdown2. There is a [comparison at cumulus network](https://support.cumulusnetworks.com/hc/en-us/articles/202933638-Comparing-ifupdown2-Commands%20) of some differences.